# Laravel Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: laravel

i'm having problem with laravel." Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" problem when i try to send data to database. Any ideas how to fix it?
I created database with phpmyadmin if u need that just say and i will include it.

index page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <table>

            <form action="store" method="post">

                <label for="name">Vardas</label>
                <input type="text" name="name"> <br>

                <label for="last-name">Pavarde</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name"> <br>

                <label for="email">email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email"> <br>

                <label for="tel.nr">tel.nr</label>
                <input type="text" name="tel.nr"> <br>

                <label for="select">Plano pasirinkimas</label><select>
                    @foreach($hostings as $hosting)
                    <option value="{{$hosting['id']}}">{{$hosting['pavadinimas']}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <br><input type="submit" value="Pateikti">

                {{csrf_field()}}

            </form>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HostController@index');
Route::get('/create', 'PostController@index');
Route::post('/store', 'PostController@store');
```

Post Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    return view('index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    Posting::create(Request::all());
    return view('index');
}
```

Model :

```
    class Posting extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'client';
    public $fillable = ['id','host_id','vardas','pavarde','Tel','email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the reference of that foreign key? Is the column that you referenced  on the other table available?